# Finding equation from log log graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

[image]

In this graph, I am asked to find out that the equation satisfies the straight line on the graph. Therefore I have evaluated the  slope of the graph  by the two coordinates, (3,10) and (300, 100 ) which are the two ends of the straight line.

The slope is,  $\frac{10}{33}$.

The answer  given is: $$y =  6\sqrt{x}$$.

My question is , cant I use the slope to find the equation? If not then what is the strategy to find the  equation?

Comment: That's exactly what you can do. Bear in mind that the equation of a line in the log-log plane is not $y=m\cdot x + b$, but rather $\log y = m \cdot \log x + b$. Work from that and you can solve for $y$ as a function of $x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an equation of the form 
$$
\ln y = a\ln x + b
$$
and the two points you have give
$$\begin{align}
\ln 10 &= a\ln 3 + b\\
\ln 100 &= a\ln 300 + b.
\end{align}$$
In particular, solving the linear system for $a,b$ you get 
$$\begin{align}
a &= \frac{\ln 10}{\ln 100} = \frac{1}{2}\\
b &= \ln 10 - \frac{1}{2}\ln 3 = \frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{100}{3}.
\end{align}$$

Plugging it back, 
$$
\ln y = \frac{1}{2}\ln x + \frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{100}{3}
$$
or, exponentiating both sides,
$$
y = \frac{10}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{x} \simeq 5.8\sqrt{x}
$$